# Copying file from Desktop to Virtual Server LINUX

Tags: linux, macos, virtual-machine, virtual-server

I have researched and only see answers on how to do this on windows, so here are my details.

I am using mac os X .. And I am connecting to a virtual server via VPN. My problem is I have files on the desktop of my mac that I need to get to the Virtual server on the VPN. How can this be accomplished. They are not on the same network, or IP range. I heard you should install a webserver onto the virtual server in order to accomplish this. Does anyone have experience with this or can provide any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X includes the scp command that can be used to copy files to a virtual server assuming that it is a Linux system running SSH. For example, this terminal command will copy the file "my_file.txt" from the current directory to username's home directory on the server. The colon at the end of the command is important.

```
scp my_file.txt username@virtual.server.ip.address:
```

The scp and sftp instructions here apply to OS X as well as Linux.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles

Comment: Thank you for this. You seem to have me on the right track. One last thing is that i keep getting scp command not found. So I tried doing yum install scp, and yum search scp and both have came up empty handed. Is there a way that you are aware of to obtain the scp package ?

Comment: the scp command words from terminal on the mac. But as soon as i put the login credentials for the server it gives me scp command not found. I'm assuming because SCP is not installed on the virtual server.. Correct ?

Comment: If you have a minimal install I believe `yum install openssh-clients` will install the missing binary.

Comment: I actually ran into a problem So i was able to successfully scp my first file over to the server. Unfortunately the second one i tried i keep getting no such file or directory when trying to do the second file. Both files are located on the desktop, and both of them are saved in the kind: Document. Not really sure how the two documents are any different that could be causing this